# How distinct a real outliers with PYod?

Tags: python, sample, outliers

I am working on an anomaly detection project on a call detail record for a telephone operator, I have prepared a sample of 10000 observations and 80 dimensions which represent the totality of the observations for a day of traffic, the data are represented as follows:

[image]

this is a small part of the whole dataset.

however, I decided to use the library PYOD which is an API that offers many unsupervised learning algorithms, I decided to start with CNN:

```
from pyod.models.knn import KNN
knn= KNN(contamination= 0.1)
result = knn.fit_predict(conso)
```

Then to visualize the result I decided to resize the sample in 2 dimentions and to display it in scatter with in blue the observations that KNN predicted that were not outliers and in red those which are outliers.

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
result_f = TSNE(n_components = 2).fit_transform(df_final_2)
result_f = pd.DataFrame(result_f)
color= ['red' if row == 1 else 'blue' for row in result_list]
```

'df_final_2' is the dataframe version of 'conso'.

then I put all that in the right colors:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(result_f[0],result_f[1], s=1, c=color)
```

[image]

The thing that disturbs me in the graph is that the observations predict as outliers are not really outliers because normally the outliers are in the extremity of the graph and not grouped with the normal behaviors, even by analyzing these obseravations aberent they have a normal behavior in the original dataset, I have tried other PYOD algorithms and I have modified the parameters of each algorithm but I have obtained at least the same result. I made a mistake somewhere and I can not distinguish it.

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to check:

- using knn, lof, and similar models that rely on distance measures, the data should be first standardized (using sklearn StandardScaler)
- tsne may now work in this case and the dimensionality reduction could be off
- maybe do not use fit_predict, but do this (use y_train_pred):

```
    # train kNN detector
    clf_name = 'KNN'
    clf = KNN(contamination=0.1)
    clf.fit(X)

    # get the prediction labels and outlier scores of the training data
    y_train_pred = clf.labels_  # binary labels (0: inliers, 1: outliers)
    y_train_scores = clf.decision_scores_  # raw outlier scores
```

If none of these work, feel free to open an issue report on GitHub and we will take a further investigation.